# How to add TSI scope combined with resource-specific scopes

Tags: python, flask, azure-timeseries-insights

I am trying to authorize the user to use my python flask application that I have built. I use the flask dance azure blueprint and define scopes to access the user information. I try to add the scope for TSI like in the picture below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGjSa.jpg). This blueprint normally generates an access token. This access token with which we have defined the TSI scope can be used to authenticate the user against the TSI . But this returns a error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR96M.jpg)
Kindly guide me through how to add TSI scope to the existing scopes of an access tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, have you tried removing the the TSI scope?  The error seems pretty descriptive, I'm guessing the .default TSI scope cannot be combined with other scopes related to graph.  That is, you are not allowed to get a single token that handles graph related scopes and TSI scopes.

That being said, I don't know anything about the make_azure_blueprint function, flask, dance etc which is probably more like what you need to solve this.  So your question is probably more like "how do I get multiple API scopes using flask dance make_azure_blueprint" since I don't think this is specific to TSI

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I also have another question.
I have a access token with which i generate session ID to access the TSI environment. I an trying to use this "session ID" , "environment name" and "tag name" as input to pull the values. I am trying to do all this with python. 
How do you think i can solve this. I do not want to use the client_id or secret to do so.